# A garment, a fictional village, or something novel

Tags: riddle, geography

I'm in the north. I can be accompanied by a garment, a fictional village, or something novel.

I'm in the south. I can be accompanied by a condiment, an indoor space, or something airborne.

I'm in the east. I can be accompanied by a dog, an athletic event, or something social.

I'm in the west. I can be accompanied by a victory, a male person, or something magnetic.

Who are we? Where are we located?

Hint:

> North, south etc. refer to our geographical location.

Hint #2:

> Watch out for cheap copies. There is a new world where one could find copies of each of us, or even our entire location. This puzzle refers to the originals, even if in some cases the new one is much better known.

Hint #3:

> Some things that used to be common are now only used when in costume.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are:

> Cities in England, UK

The clues hint at:

> Words that can be combined with the city name to form compound words

In the North is

> York, North Yorkshire
>
>  - Garment -> [Cape York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_York_Peninsula), A peninsula in Queensland, Australia. (Thanks to @MOehm)
>  - Fictional Village -> York**shire**, The Shire being the fictional hometown of Bilbo Baggins in The Hobbit
>  - Something Novel -> **New** York

In the South is

> Bath, Somerset
>
>  - Condiment -> Bath **Salts**
>  - Indoor Space -> Bath**room**
>  - Something Airborne -> **Bird** Bath

In the East is

> Boston, Lincolnshire
>
>  - Dog -> Boston **Terrier**
>  - Athletic Event -> Boston **Marathon**
>  - Something Social -> Boston **Tea Party**

In the West is

> Chester, Cheshire
>
>  - Victory -> **Win**chester
>  - Male Person -> **Man**chester (these last two are both UK cities as well)
>  - Something Magnetic -> Chester**field**, Magnets produce magnetic fields, and a Chesterfield is an item of furniture. (Thanks to @HughMeyers for this one)

Comment: Well done, 3/4 correct! :) For the last one I was thinking about something else, although your answer fits the clues really well too.

Comment: I've added another guess for "West" which, again, only hits 2/3 clues. Am I getting closer?

Comment: Yeah, that's it :)

Comment: In 4, there's a piece of furniture whose last part could be something magnetic.

Comment: @HughMeyers Thanks for the hint! This must be it...

Comment: I think the garment can also be a coastline feature The one that can be combined with 1 is in Queensland.

Comment: @MOehm aha! Thanks! That's all the clues answered!

Comment: The Shire is not a village; it's a *region* in Middle-Earth. <nerd-rage>

Answer (score 9):

I got surprisingly far with

> The letter **T**.

I'm in the north. I can be accompanied by a garment, a fictional village, or something novel.

> nor**t**h, **T**-shirt, ?, new**t**

I'm in the south. I can be accompanied by a condiment, an indoor space, or something airborne.

> sou**t**h, ?, **tea** room, [**T**-bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Thunderbird)

I'm in the east. I can be accompanied by a dog, an athletic event, or something social.

> eas**t**, **T**-rex, **t**race, **tea** party

I'm in the west. I can be accompanied by a victory, a male person, or something magnetic.

> wes**t**, **t**win, **t**he, Ni**t** (Nickel is one of the four ferromagnetic elements)

Comment: You don't keep a T-rex at home do you? If so, you have a good security plan ; )

Comment: Very nice work, but not what I had in mind. I have added a hint.

Comment: @jafe yeah, thought as much from the question being "who are we", but since a couple of the clues fit amazingly well, decided to post anyway.